# `asyncio.get_event_loop()` works in plain python but not in ipython

Tags: python, python-asyncio, ipython

I observe different behavior of `asyncio.get_event_loop()` in plain `python` console and in `ipython`.

Plain `python` - all as expected:

```py
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import asyncio
>>> asyncio.get_event_loop()
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
<_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>
```

`ipython` - getting the event loop fails:

```py
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.21.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import asyncio

In [2]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-2-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 asyncio.get_event_loop()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.6/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py:656, in BaseDefaultEventLoopPolicy.get_event_loop(self)
    653     self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
    655 if self._local._loop is None:
--> 656     raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
    657                        % threading.current_thread().name)
    659 return self._local._loop

RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

Moreover, creating and setting a loop explicitly doesn't work in IPython too:

```py
In [3]: loop = asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

In [4]: asyncio.get_event_loop()
<ipython-input-4-6908e23590ee>:1: DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
  asyncio.get_event_loop()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
[...]
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.
```

The error is reproducible in some environment but not in the others:

```
-----------------------------------------
host OS  |  runs in Docker* |  reproduced 
-----------------------------------------
Ubuntu   |       yes        |     yes**
Ubuntu   |        no        |      no
MacOS    |       yes        |      no
MacOS    |        no        |      no
```

`*` - `docker -it python:3.10`

`**` - reproduced on 2 different machines

Any tips on what may go wrong with the version in IPython?

Comment: #worksforme  - maybe, update your iPython version? ( pip -U ipython ) ?

Comment: Updating IPython version didn't help :( Thanks for the suggestion anyway!